# Are dihedral groups $D_{2n}$ alternatively generated by $n$ reflections?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $a,b,c$ be reflections across a regular triangles lines of reflective symmetry.  Then $a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1$.  Label the triangle $\triangle= (1,2,3)$.  Then $a\triangle = (2,1,3)$, $ab\triangle = (2,3,1) = r\triangle$ where $r$ is a left rotation of the labels.  From this, how do I prove that $D_{2n}$, for $n=3$ is generated by $a,b,c$?

Comment: How many elements doe the subgroup generated by the three element have?

Comment: I'm assuming your standard definition of $D_{2n}$ is the group generated by $x,y$ where $y$ is reflection about a chosen axis and $x$ is rotation by $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. If so, can you relate the elements in this definition to the elements in your alternative characterization? There's 6 elements in each so set up the correct bijection, and show it is a homomorphism.